# Use jQuery to .post() to ASP MVC controller method w/Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How would you use jQuery to post to a different controller using Razor syntax? Below is the code I'm attempting to use. Each of the alerts pop up the exact information I am expecting except for the one containing the `@Url.Action`. This gives me a URL that just contains the Controller and method (i.e. `/Agent/Details`). The `sNumber` is completely missing.

Oddly enough, this code is still posting to the controller properly, with the correct `sNumber` parameter. However, once the controller goes through the process of grabbing the agent from the database and attempting to render the view, nothing happens. The user stays on the same page.

Here is the jQuery

```
                alert("input: " + item + ", map: " + map[item].sNumber);
                var sNumber = map[item].sNumber;
                alert("variable: " + sNumber);

                alert('@Url.Action("Details","Agent")', { id: sNumber });
                $.post('@Url.Action("Details","Agent")', { id: sNumber });
```

There is a ton of code in controller, so I'll spare you by not posting it. However, this is the final line

```
return View(bigAgent);
```

The controller uses the `sNumber` input parameter to grab the record from our database and pass that agent's info to the `Details` view. I've checked the contents of the `bigAgent` object using both the jQuery search and our regular search (which redirects properly), and they are one and the same. For whatever reason, you are just not directed to the `Details` page when using the jQuery search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not odd that it's posting correctly. You are using a POST request afterall, so the `sNumber` parameter doesn't belong in the URL as it would with a `GET` request (e.g. `/Agent/Details/3`).

You're not being redirected because when you use jQuery AJAX methods, they happen asynchronously. You need to handle the redirect yourself in the success callback of the `$.post()` function.

```
$.post('url', { data }, function(data) {
    // callback
});
```

It sort of seems like you shouldn't be using AJAX at all and should be performing a regular form submission so you can handle the redirect in your controller.